# How to sort alphabetically within a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm an intermediate Ruby developer. I'm working on some puzzles to brush up on Ruby and I'm trying to figure out how to go about sorting a multidimensional array.
Here's my code:

```
myArray = [['Jones', 'Layla'], ['Smith', 'Gary'], ['Williams', 'Nick'] ,['Brown', 'Kyle']]
```

So I need to iterate through the array and through the sub-arrays, identify the last names, and alphabetize them. For some reason nothing I've been trying for the last two hours seems to be working. I've been searching high and low online. Can anyone help out? I've been trying variations of the following, below. Any pointers?

```
myArray.each { |sub_array| 
sub_array.sort_by! { |x|
x[0].downcase #the x[0] element being the last name, which is the first element in each of the sub-arrays
    }
return sub_array
}
```

edit: forgot to clarify, the end result should look like this:

```
myArray = [['Brown', 'Kyle']['Jones', 'Layla'], ['Smith', 'Gary'], ['Williams', 'Nick']]
```

Comment: What is the desired result applied to `myArray`? What do you mean with "alphabetize them"?

Comment: Sorry,  should have clarified that. The end result should look like the above edit I made -- basically, the sub-arrays should be sorted according to last name, alphabetically.

Comment: Don't feel pressured by requests from members to accept their answers. For one, you don't want to discourage other answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a few hours before awarding the greenie.  If a day or more has gone by and you have not made a selection, it's reasonable for anyone to make a gentle request that you consider selecting the answer you found most helpful (but not a specific answer!). If you don't find any of the answers helpful, there is no reason to apply the ✅.

Comment: BTW, there are no multidimensional arrays in Ruby (unless you count `Matrix` from the standard library I suppose), you have a simple array-of-arrays.

Comment: ...and `Matrix` only supports two-dimensional matrices, not multi-dimensional matrices generally.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. I'm still somewhat of a new person here so I wasn't sure exactly how the system works. In the future, I'll definitely wait to see if anyone has any other suggestions about what answers to give. @CarySwoveland
also thank you for the clarification, muistooshort. I was mistaken about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sort the array by the lastname (the first element of each sub array) you could do easily with this:

`myArray.sort { |x,y| x[0] <=> y[0] }`

```
myArray = [['Jones', 'Layla'], ['Smith', 'Gary'], ['Williams', 'Nick'], ['Brown', 'Kyle']]
 => [["Jones", "Layla"], ["Smith", "Gary"], ["Williams", "Nick"], ["Brown", "Kyle"]] 
myArray.sort { |x,y| x[0] <=> y[0] }
 => [["Brown", "Kyle"], ["Jones", "Layla"], ["Smith", "Gary"], ["Williams", "Nick"]]
```

`sort` documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)

Comment: Thanks so much! Wow, this answer was not too hard to come by at all. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Leia_Organa glad to help you! Please accept the answer if is correct :)

Comment: You should *always* use `sort_by` for a keyed sort. Not only is it easier to read (that's the important bit), it also happens to be more efficient (that's the unimportant, but nice-to-have side-effect). I.e. use `myArray.sort_by {|el| el[0] }` or simply `myArray.sort_by(&:first)`. Plus, arrays are sorted lexicographically, so the *real* answer is just `myArray.sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) without a block:

```
my_array = [['Jones', 'Layla'], ['Smith', 'Gary'], ['Williams', 'Nick'],
            ['Brown', 'Kyle']]
my_array.sort
   #=> [["Brown", "Kyle"], ["Jones", "Layla"], ["Smith", "Gary"], ["Williams", "Nick"]]
```

See the doc for the method [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (the *spaceship operator*) to learn how Ruby orders each pair of arrays within the sorting algorithm.

If two people have the same last name, `sort` will order them by their first name (i.e., first names are used to break ties):

```
my_array = [['Jones', 'Layla'], ['Smith', 'Gary'], ['Williams', 'Nick'],
            ['Brown', 'Kyle'], ['Jones', 'Zack']]

my_array.sort
  #=> [["Brown", "Kyle"], ["Jones", "Layla"], ["Jones", "Zack"],
  #    ["Smith", "Gary"], ["Williams", "Nick"]]
```

I used `my_array` instead of `myArray` because the Ruby convention is to use "snake-case" for names of variables and methods. You don't have to follow that convention, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Apparently that was not as hard as it needed to be. Also thanks for the tip about snake_case. I am very used to using CamelCase for most of my code, it's hard to get into the swing.